# Get previous search result

Tags: mutt

When I've started a search in Mutt with <kbd>/</kbd>, I can go to the next search result with <kbd>n</kbd>, easy.

But what if I want to go the *other* direction and see the previous search result, i.e., the previously matching email?

Is there a key binding for that? In Vim, this is <kbd>N</kbd>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Mutt 1.11.4, there's no key binding for getting the previous search result, but it's easy to add one to `muttrc`:

```
bind index N search-opposite
# Ctrl-n toggles whether a mail is considered new or not
bind index \cn toggle-new
```

Because <kbd>N</kbd> is by default mapped to `toggle-new`, I remapped that to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>.

Since we're at it, we can make Mutt behave a little bit more like Vim by mapping <kbd>?</kbd> to start a backward search (which is by default mapped to <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>).

```
bind index ? search-reverse
# ? used to show help, so we remap that
bind index <F1> help
```